# How to make All 3 conditions in Autohotkey (how to code "AND")

Tags: windows-10, script, autohotkey, code

I have a simple autohotkey code, but I cannot figure out how to make all 3 conditions met before doing the rules in the first bracket.

My code functions like, if any one condition is met, it will proceed. But I want to all 3 conditions met before proceeding.

The conditions should be:

1. the title of the window must be September-Sales.
2. the window must be Microsoft Word
3. process winword.exe

```
Start:

IfWinExist, September-Sales ; (Title of the Microsoft Word Window)

if WinExist("ahk_class OpusApp")    ; class

if WinExist("ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE")  ; process
{
    WinActivate
    SendInput, {Tab}
    SendInput, {Invoice Category}
    SendInput, {Enter}
}

else 
    msgbox, Call the Encoder and give the O.R. Number.
Return
End
```

Comment: Have you tried if(this && that) {...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Autohotkey documentation on [IfWinExist / IfWinNotExist / WinExist](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm) provides an example of multiple conditions.

> if WinExist("ahk_class Notepad") or WinExist("ahk_class" . ClassName)

For your purposes, you would want the following code

```
if WinExist("September-Sales") and WinExist("ahk_class OpusApp") and WinExist("ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE")
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but doesn't worked. It's OR, not AND. I don't know how to put "AND," and the way to code it.

Comment: Edited to add specific code example. I've just opened a word document and tried to run the code I gave (replacing '...' with Msgbox) and it didn't run. Saved document as 'September-Sales' and reran it and it worked.

Comment: Actually, we will use it with Sublime_Text ("ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS" and  "ahk_exe sublime_text.exe"), not MS-Word (I just said that because im not sure if people here are familiar with SublimeText). Yes, it worked with just the Title and Class, but won't work with the 3rd condition, so I removed the "ahk_exe sublime_text.exe" condition. How can we include the third condition?

Comment: "September-Sales" isn't probaly the exact title of the window. In this case you need **`SetTitleMatchMode, 2`** and **`If WinExist("September-Sales ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS ahk_exe sublime_text.exe")`**.  See [Multiple Criteria](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#multi) and [SetTitleMatchMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm).

Comment: Hi Robbie W. - It's working right here now. Thank you very much.. :-). We just used your given "If WinExist("September-Sales ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS ahk_exe sublime_text.exe")".. About the SetTitleMatchMode, we don't know what it is for, but it's working perfectly here now.

Comment: I didn't even realise you could add multiple criteria so +1 @user3419297. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending your statements too early with the ';' operator.

```
if WinExist("ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE") &&  WinExist("ahk_class OpusApp")
{
    WinActivate
    SendInput, {Tab}
    SendInput, {Invoice Category}
    SendInput, {Enter}
}
else 
{
    msgbox, Call the Encoder and give the O.R. Number.
}
Return
```